# are there any functions for closing turtle graphics's window?

Tags: python, function, turtle-graphics

so I want my program to do some lines of code then open turtle window do some staff, close it, do some code again and open turtle window. I have tried `turtle.clear()`, `turtle.reset()`, `turtle.resetscreen()`, `turtle.clearscreen()`, `turtle.exitonclick()`, but none of it clears entirely, close it and when I need it again, gives me ability to open it.
so can you help me.

Answer (score -1):

```
import turtle, time
screen = turtle.Screen()
turtle.color('orange')
turtle.pensize(3)
turtle.circle(75)

time.sleep(5)

# close
screen.bye()
# or turtle.Screen().bye()
```